# sed: removing alphanumeric words from a file

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I have file with a lot of text, what I want to do is to remove all alphanumeric words.

```
Example of words to be removed:

gr8  
2006  
sdlfj435ljsa  
232asa  
asld213  
ladj2343asda
asd!32
```

what is the best way I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove all words that consist of letters and digits, leaving only words that consist of all digits or all letters:

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\+[[:digit:]]\+[[:alnum:]]*\|[[:digit:]]\+[[:alpha:]]\+[[:alnum:]]*\) \?//g' inputfile
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'abc def ghi 111 222 ab3 a34 43a a34a 4ab3' | sed 's/\<\([[:alpha:]]\+[[:digit:]]\+[[:alnum:]]*\|[[:digit:]]\+[[:alpha:]]\+[[:alnum:]]*\) \?//g'
abc def ghi 111 222
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the only output you wanted from your sample text is `2006` and you have one word per line:

```
 sed '/[[:alpha:]]\+/{/[[:digit:]]\+/d}' /path/to/alnum/file
```

#### Input

```
$ cat alnum
gr8
2006
sdlFj435ljsa
232asa
asld213
ladj2343asda
asd!32
alpha
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/[[:alpha:]]\+/{/[[:digit:]]\+/d}' ./alnum
2006
alpha
```

Comment: using the `;/^$/d'` command would clean up the output. For example `sed '/[[:alpha:]]\+/{/[[:digit:]]\+/s/.*//g}' alnum` would return `2006` and `alpha` on single lines

Comment: Appreciate the comment.  Haven't looked at this answer for almost 5 years but now that I've looked at it in light of your comment I delete the line in lieu of substituting it with an empty line.

Comment: nice work, that one even removed the command chaining. I'm impressed and learnt something new at the same time. +1

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is actually to remove all alphanumeric words (strings consisting entirely of letters and digits) then this `sed` command will work.  It replaces all alphanumeric strings with nothing.

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]]*//g' < inputfile
```

Note that other character classes besides `alnum` are also available (see `man 7 regex`).

For your given example data, this leaves only 6 blank lines and a single `!` (since that is the only non-alphanumeric character in the example data).  Is this actually what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

[AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) solution:

```
BEGIN { # Statement that will be executed once at the beginning.
    FS="[ \t]" # Set space and tab characters to be treated as word separator.
}
# Code below will execute for each line in file.
{
    x=1  # Set initial word index to 1 (0 is the original string in array)
    fw=1 # Indicate that future matched word is a first word. This is needed to put newline and spaces correctly.
    while ( x<=NF )
    {
        gsub(/[ \t]*/,"",$x) # Strip word. Remove any leading and trailing white-spaces.
        if (!match($x,"^[A-Za-z0-9]*$")) # Print word only if it does not match pure alphanumeric set of characters.
        {
            if (fw == 0)
            {
                printf (" %s", $x) # Print the word offsetting it with space in case if this is not a first match.
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("%s", $x) # Print word as is...
                fw=0 # ...and indicate that future matches are not first occurrences
            }
        }
        x++ # Increase word index number.
    }
    if (fw == 0) # Print newline only if we had matched some words and printed something.
    {
        printf ("\n")
    }
}
```

Assuming you have this script in `script.awk' and data in`data.txt`, you have to invoke`awk` like this:

```
awk -f ./test.awk ./data.txt
```

For your file it will produce:

```
asd!32
```

For more complex cases like this:

```
gr8
2006
sdlfj435ljsa
232asa  he!he lol
asld213  f
ladj2343asda
asd!32  ab acd!s
```

... it will produce this:

```
he!he
asd!32 acd!s
```

Hope it helps.
Good luck!